# Use CXF libraries in Wildfly deployment with Maven artifact provided

Tags: java, web-services, maven, jax-ws, wildfly

Im trying to deploy a project containing an JAX-WS Interface to a wildfly 8.2 server. The project is packed as a war.
Within that project I would like to use interceptors.

```
import org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.AbstractSoapInterceptor;
public class ReplyToHeaderInInterceptor extends AbstractSoapInterceptor { /*code*/}
```

I'm using Maven with the "provided" tag, in order to not receiving the following error:

```
Apache CXF library (cxf-rt-bindings-soap-3.1.1.jar) detected in ws endpoint deployment; either provide a proper deployment replacing embedded libraries with container module dependencies or disable the webservices subsystem for the current deployment adding a proper jboss-deployment-structure.xml descriptor to it. The former approach is recommended, as the latter approach causes most of the webservices Java EE and any JBossWS specific functionality to be disabled.
```

That looks like this:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

But if I do so the library cannot be found at runtime:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/cxf/binding/soap/interceptor/AbstractSoapInterceptor
```

I have already tried adding the dependency via the MANIFEST.MF file using maven:

```
            <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <configuration>
                <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/web.xml</packagingExcludes>
                <warName>backend</warName>
               <archive>
                  <manifestEntries>
                     <Dependencies>org.apache.cxf</Dependencies>
                  </manifestEntries>
               </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

I don't know what to do, any suggestions?

Comment: Did you include the mapping of the interceptor in any spring config file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turned out adding a `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` file to `WEB-INF` folder with the following content did the trick:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <deployment>
        <exclusions>
        </exclusions>
        <dependencies>
            <module name="org.apache.cxf" />
            <module name="org.apache.cxf.impl" />
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Eventhough I tried it before with `org.apache.cxf` only,I had to add `org.apache.cxf.impl`

Comment: Amazing! Just what I wanted. Pitty it doesn't work for me :( afer several hours of tweaking. All deps in poms with scope provided? Meaning, I have a war and an ear too; maybe it's not your case.

Comment: Probably the answer about disabling webservices replies to this (with yes).

Answer (score 4):

The other option is to use your own structure, than the modules(versions) offered in Wildfly server deployment. This is done with jboss-deployment-structure.xml file to WEB-INF with this content:

```
  <deployment>
    <exclude-subsystems>
        <subsystem name="webservices" /> 
    </exclude-subsystems>  
  </deployment>
```

This will disable webservice framework included in Wildfly and use war included libraries(lib jars)

This is mentioned in related question/answer:
[How to access CXF jars from Wildfly (Jboss) for ws endpoints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29407115/how-to-access-cxf-jars-from-wildfly-jboss-for-ws-endpoints][1])