# camel cxf on wildfly

Tags: java, apache-camel, cxf, wildfly

I'v created a SOAP webservice and I'd like to expose it with camel-cxf on wildfly.

When I want to deploy it I get the following error:

> Apache CXF library (cxf-core-3.2.0.jar) detected in ws endpoint deployment; either provide a proper deployment replacing embedded libraries with container module dependencies or disable the webservices subsystem for the current deployment adding a proper jboss-deployment-structure.xml descriptor to it. The former approach is recommended, as the latter approach causes most of the webservices Java EE and any JBossWS specific functionality to be disabled.

Tried what was suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31099208/use-cxf-libraries-in-wildfly-deployment-with-maven-artifact-provided#35697381) but didn't work. Tried to exclude the cxf dependencies from the caml-cxf include in my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
   <artifactId>camel-cxf</artifactId>
   <version>2.20.0</version>
   <exclusions>
     <exclusion>
         <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
          <artifactId>*</artifactId>
     </exclusion>
   </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

That solved the error but produces new ones:

```
Failed to define class org.apache.camel.component.cxf.spring.AbstractCxfBeanDefinitionParser in Module "deployment.CamelCXF-1.0.war" from Service Module Loader: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link org/apache/camel/component/cxf/spring/AbstractCxfBeanDefinitionParser

Failed to define class org.apache.camel.component.cxf.spring.CxfEndpointBeanDefinitionParser in Module "deployment.CamelCXF-1.0.war" from Service Module Loader: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link org/apache/camel/component/cxf/spring/CxfEndpointBeanDefinitionParser

Context initialization failed: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/camel.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException: Invalid NamespaceHandler class [org.apache.camel.component.cxf.spring.NamespaceHandler] for namespace [http://camel.apache.org/schema/cxf]: problem with handler class file or dependent class; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link org/apache/camel/component/cxf/spring/CxfEndpointBeanDefinitionParser
```

Could you help me resolve these errors or provide a small working example that I can deploy on wildfly and extend? Much appreciated.

Defined these dependencies in my pom.xml:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.20.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-cxf</artifactId>
        <version>2.20.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                <artifactId>*</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>8.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

And here's my camel.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:camel="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:cxf="http://camel.apache.org/schema/cxf"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
   http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring 
    http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://camel.apache.org/schema/cxf
http://camel.apache.org/schema/cxf/camel-cxf.xsd">

<cxf:cxfEndpoint id="customerEndpoint"
                 address="http://localhost:8080/TestService/"
                 serviceClass="my.package.TestService"
                 wsdlURL="WEB-INF/CustomerService.wsdl"/>

<bean id="logBean" class="my.package.LogBean"/>

<camel:camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <route>
        <from uri="cxf:bean:customerEndpoint" /> 
        <to uri="bean:logBean" />
    </route>
</camel:camelContext>
```

### Follow-up question

I could set up a webservice with the links provided by @Tadayoshi Sato. The examples, however, only use one simple function with one processor. How do I know which function was called when I have several operations in a port definition?
Is it possible to have camel call the implementation of the provided interface that was called or do I have to map that myself?

Comment: You may want to look at wildfly-camel which is intended for running Camel on WildFly / JBoss EAP as sub-modules. https://github.com/wildfly-extras/wildfly-camel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Claus pointed out, the most recommended approach to use Camel on WildFly is using WildFly Camel. You can find in the link below how to install the WildFly Camel subsystem to WildFly:
http://wildfly-extras.github.io/wildfly-camel/index.html

Once you've installed WildFly Camel, let's see this link, where you can find how to develop code using camel-cxf on WildFly:
http://wildfly-extras.github.io/wildfly-camel/index.html#_jax_ws

The point is that WildFly already has its own CXF libraries as a subsystem and you are required to use the built-in libraries as much as possible; otherwise, you may encounter awkward problems like those in the question. It's the WildFly Camel subsystem that lets you to use the underlying WildFly subsystems for your Camel applications.

**UPDATE:**

For camel-cxf consumers, the operation name which is called is available via `CxfConstants.OPERATION_NAME` message header. According to:
https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-cxf/src/main/docs/cxf-component.adoc

> The camel-cxf endpoint consumer POJO data format is based on the [CXF invoker](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/invokers.html), so the message header has a property with the name of `CxfConstants.OPERATION_NAME` and the message body is a list of the SEI method parameters.

You may [route a message based on this message header](http://camel.apache.org/content-based-router.html) and change the implementations accordingly.

Comment: Thank you. That helped me run a webservice with camel-cxf. Do you by chance know the answer to my follow-up question, too?

Comment: Thank you. It seems to work =) Since I'm trying to use XML to define my camel routes I had to use `${header.soapAction|operationName}`. I think when using it in Java code you'd need to import **camel-cxf-transport** (at least that's what I deduced from [here](https://camel.apache.org/maven/camel-2.15.0/camel-cxf/apidocs/org/apache/camel/component/cxf/CxfConstants.html). Also interestring to know is that when using several parameters then you'd want to call your bean like so: `<to uri="bean:MyServiceImpl?method=myMethod&amp;multiParameterArray=true"/>`